# R: IF statement evaluating expression despite condition being FALSE?

Tags: r, if-statement, nested, match

I've got a large function in R and the users have the ability to not include/specify an object. If they DO, the code checks to make sure the names in that object match the names in another. If they DON'T, there's no need to do that checking. The code line is:

```
if(exists("grids")) if(!all(expvarnames %in% names(grids))) {stop("Not all expvar column names found as column names in grids")}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : argument "grids" is missing, with no default
```

Well in this trial run, grids is SUPPOSED to be missing. If I try

```
if(exists("grids")) print("yay")
```

Then nothing prints, i.e. the absence of grids means the expression isn't evaluated, which is as I'd expect. So can anyone think why R seems to be evaluating the subsequent IF statement in the main example? Should I slap another set of curly brackets around the second one??

Thanks!

Edit: more problems. Removing "grids," from the functions list of variables means it works if there's no object called grids and you don't specify it in the call (i.e. `function(x,grids=whatever)`). And keeping "grids," IN the functions list of variables means it works if there IS an object called grids and you do specify it in the call.

Please see this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkFqd.png

using `exists(grids)` is out because exists wants "quotes" and without em everything fails. WITH them ("grids"), I need to decide whether to keep "grids," in the functions list. If I don't, but I specify it in the call `(function(x,grids=whatever))` then I get unused argument fail. If I DO, but don't specify it in the call because grids doesn't exist and I don't want to use it, I get match error, grids missing no default.

How do I get around this? Maybe list it in the function variables list as `grids="NULL"`, then rather than `if(exists("grids"))` do `if(grids!="NULL")`

I still don't know why the original match problem is happening though. Match is from the expvarnames/grids names checker, which is AFTER `if(exists("grids"))` which evaluates to FALSE. WAaaaaaaiiiiittttt..... If I specify grids in the function variables list, i.e. simply putting `function(x,grids,etc){do stuff}`, does that mean the function CREATES an object called grids, within its environment?
Man this is so f'd up....

```
testfun <- function(x,grids)
{if(exists("grids")) globalgrids<<-grids
print(x+1)}
testfun(1) # Error in testfun(1) : argument "grids" is missing, with no default

testfun <- function(x,grids)
{if(exists("grids")) a<<-c(1,2,3)
  print(x+1)}
testfun(1) #2 (and globally assigns a)
```

So in the first example, the function seems to have created an object called "grids" because exists("grids") evaluates to true. But THEN, ON THE SAME LINE, when asked to do something with grids, it says it doesn't exist! Schroedinger's object?!
This is proven in example 2: grids evaluates true and a is globally assigned then the function does its thing. Madness. Complete madness. Does anyone know WHY this ridiculousness is going on? And is the best solution to use my grids="NULL" default in the functions variables list?
Thanks.

Reproducible example, if you want to but I've already done it for every permutation:

```
testfun <- function(x,grids)
{if(exists("grids")) if(!all(expvarnames %in% names(grids))) {stop("Not all expvar column names found as column names in grids")}
  print(x+1)}
testfun(1)
testfun(x=1,grids=grids)
grids<-data.frame(c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3))
expvarnames <- c("a","b","c")
colnames(grids) <- c("a","b","c")
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example please. `argument "grids" is missing, with no default` is interesting and suspect.  Is `grids` an argument to your function?

Comment: I suspect that "grids" shouldn't have quotes

Comment: Unfortunately I initially tried without the quotes, but got: "Error in exists(grids) : object 'grids' not found". Which is what I want....but the error breaks the code! Grids is an argument to my function, yes, with no default, so simply "..., grids, ..." in the function's elements list.

Comment: Richard's comment got me thinking: grids was an argument in my function but was optional, so maybe shouldn't be specified (like anything in "..." optional functions). I commented it out and it worked. Hooray, cheers everyone.

Comment: see updated question. Problem semi solved but has revealed super-weird illogic in R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

Adapting your example use:

```
testfun <- function(x,grids = NULL)
{
   if(!is.null(grids)){
     if(!all(expvarnames %in% names(grids))){
       stop("Not all expvar column names found as column names in grids")
     }
     print(x+1)
   }
}
```

Using this `testfun(1)` will return nothing. By specifying a default argument in the function as `NULL` the function then checks for this (i.e. no argument specified) and then doesn't continue the function if so.

**The Reason the Problem Occurs**

We go through each of the examples:

```
testfun <- function(x,grids)
{if(exists("grids")) globalgrids<<-grids
print(x+1)}

testfun(1) # Error in testfun(1) : argument "grids" is missing, with no default
```

Here we call the function `testfun`, giving only the `x` argument. `testfun` knows it needs two arguments, and so creates local variables `x` and `grids`. We have then given an argument to `x` and so it assigns the value to `x`. There is no argument to `grids`, however the variable has still been created, even though no value has been assigned to it. So `grids` exists, but has no value.

From this `exists("grids")` will be `TRUE`, but when we try to do `globalgrids<<-grids` we will get an error as `grids` has not been assigned a value, and so we can't assign anything to `globalgrids`.

```
testfun <- function(x,grids)
{if(exists("grids")) a<<-c(1,2,3)
  print(x+1)}
testfun(1) #2 (and globally assigns a)
```

This, however is fine. `grids` exists as in the previous case, and we never actually try and access the value stored in `grids`, which would cause an error as we have not assigned one.

In the solution, we simply set a default value for `grids`, which means we can always get something whenever we try and access the variable. Unlike in the previous cases, we will get `NULL`, not that nothing is stored there.

The main point of this is that when you declare arguments in your function, they are created each time you use the function. They exist. However, if you don't assign them values in your function call then they will exist, but have no value. Then when you try and use them, their lack of values will throw an error.

Comment: Hi JC, thanks for the answer. I'll look into the string element. My problem is the opposite though: 2 IS being evaluated and the code IS reaching "stop(etc)" even though it shouldn't be, as grids is absent (as an object or a string).

But I'll try with treating grids as an...object, I guess? By removing the quotes.

Comment: without the quotes, I get: "Error in exists(grids) : object 'grids' not found". Which is what I want....but the error breaks the code!

Comment: OK, I've looked at the exists function and it does need to be a string, so keep it as "grids". The only thing I can think of is that this is inside a function. Do you also have a global variable (not inside a function) called grids. If you do then this statement will be evaluating that variable.

Comment: Hi again. If I have a global variable called grids and call it in the function call then it should be evaluated, which is correct behaviour. But if I DON'T have one globally, exists("grids") should evaluate FALSE and not move on to the expression...which it IS doing. I've updated the question after some hours of debugging, to reveal an unlikely and confusing outcome.

Comment: Hi J, yes it does. I've been using if(grids!="NULL"), but yours is neater. I'd still be very interested if anyone knows WHY this problem is occurring though...

Answer (score 1):

```
> a <- c(1,2,3,4)
> b <- c(2,4,6,8)
> if(exists("a")) if(!all(a %in% b)) {stop("Not all a in b")}

Error: Not all a in b

> rm(a)
> if(exists("a")) if(!all(a %in% b)) {stop("Not all a in b")}
>
```

When `a` does not exist, the expression does not evaluate, as expected. Before testing your first expression, make sure that `grids` does not exist by running `rm(grids)` in the console.

Comment: Thanks GP. Unfortunately grids definitely doesn't exist. As I say, running "if(exists("grids")) print("yay")" prints nothing, as expected.

Comment: Does 'grids' exist in the function's environment, or outside the environment? Are you running both lines of code within the same function?

Comment: Both lines are used within the function. Removing "grids," from the function's list of variables solves this problem... kinda. I'm updating the question after doing some extensive research into this.

Comment: If `grids` is an argument to the function, why don't you set its default value to `NA` or null and instead of checking if `grids` exists, check if it's null or `NA`?

Comment: Hi G, I've sortof done that now based on my own deductions and JCollerton's suggestions. I'm still perplexed as to why it's going wrong in this way though...

Answer (score 0):

Richard Scriven's comment got me thinking: grids was an argument in my function but was optional, so maybe shouldn't be specified (like anything in "..." optional functions). I commented it out and it worked. Hooray, cheers everyone.

Comment: edit: if only it were that simple. See updated question.